# laravel filament very slow

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

At the moment, I'm engaged in a project that employs Laravel's Filemant, and I've noticed significant slowness when navigating between pages or submitting forms. The delay can range from 10 to 18 seconds.
My development environment is :
Wampserver Windows 10, an Intel Core i7 7th Gen CPU, 16 GB of RAM, and an SSD drive.
[The screenshot shows the problem I'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAeAO.png)

While viewing tutorials on Laravel Filament, I haven't observed them encountering this issue.
I did not understand the problem and did not find the solution. Please help.

Comment: Most likely something you are connecting to is slow, are you using and external api or an external database?

Comment: Sometimes it cause by a debugger. Since the page waiting for a code editor for bugs or error that's why the page taking up some time loading the page(s). Please check if you are using a debugger like 'XDebug'.

Comment: @mrhn thank u for response,
no it's a fresh app and i don't use any external api or external database

Comment: @Newbee I disabled Debugger first in the .env file and did not notice any change, or is there another way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The use of external icons blade and the Windows environment is also one of the reasons why the Filament is very slow.
`php artisan icons:cache` solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

A few things might be there, but you might have issues with "debugbar". It does not play very nicely with Filament and adds much rendering time to your page.

Try to:

1. Run (if you haven't) `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"`
2. Open `config/debugbar.php`
3. Change `views` value from `true` to `false`

Reload the page and see if that helped.

A few posts are already in the community with this specific problem and performance issue. It can affect the speed up to tens of seconds for no apparent reason.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work.

Comment: Try to run locally: `php artisan cache` and see if that helps. If so, there's something that needs caching, or it's just a Windows issue.

I have created quite a big project with Filament but haven't seen any other issue than debug bar that would affect performance

Comment: you are right there's something that needs caching, which is external icons package and `php artisan icons:cache` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are three potential solutions to your issue:

1. Execute the following command to cache the icons:

   ```
      php artisan icons:cache
   ```
2. If you are utilizing the debug bar, consider publishing the configuration file and disabling the views:
   `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"`
   Then, in the `config\debuggar` file, set the **views** option to false within the collections array.
3. If you have an ad blocker extension enabled in your browser, try turning it off. Sometimes, this can resolve the problem. This approach worked for me.