# why laravel debugbar not working with filament?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, laravel-filament, phpdebugbar

"I encountered an issue after successfully installing Laravel Debugbar following these steps:

1. Used **`composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev`** to install the Debugbar.
2. Published assets.
3. Enabled debug mode.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNY08.png)

However, despite these steps, I am only seeing a specific screen without any functionality. Can you please help me troubleshoot this problem? I have ensured a clear title and provided detailed information about my issue. Although I attempted some background research, it didn't yield a solution. I have tried my best to use correct English spelling and grammar.

[the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNY08.png)

this my config file
`<?php

return [

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Debugbar Settings
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Debugbar is enabled by default, when debug is set to true in app.php.
 | You can override the value by setting enable to true or false instead of null.
 |
 | You can provide an array of URI's that must be ignored (eg. 'api/*')
 |
 */

'enabled' => env('DEBUGBAR_ENABLED', null),
'except' => [
    'telescope*',
    'horizon*',
],

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Storage settings
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | DebugBar stores data for session/ajax requests.
 | You can disable this, so the debugbar stores data in headers/session,
 | but this can cause problems with large data collectors.
 | By default, file storage (in the storage folder) is used. Redis and PDO
 | can also be used. For PDO, run the package migrations first.
 |
 | Warning: Enabling storage.open will allow everyone to access previous
 | request, do not enable open storage in publicly available environments!
 | Specify a callback if you want to limit based on IP or authentication.
 */
'storage' => [
    'enabled'    => true,
    'open'       => env('DEBUGBAR_OPEN_STORAGE', false), // bool/callback.
    'driver'     => 'file', // redis, file, pdo, socket, custom
    'path'       => storage_path('debugbar'), // For file driver
    'connection' => null,   // Leave null for default connection (Redis/PDO)
    'provider'   => '', // Instance of StorageInterface for custom driver
    'hostname'   => '127.0.0.1', // Hostname to use with the "socket" driver
    'port'       => 2304, // Port to use with the "socket" driver
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Editor
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Choose your preferred editor to use when clicking file name.
|
| Supported: "phpstorm", "vscode", "vscode-insiders", "vscode-remote",
|            "vscode-insiders-remote", "vscodium", "textmate", "emacs",
|            "sublime", "atom", "nova", "macvim", "idea", "netbeans",
|            "xdebug", "espresso"
|
*/

'editor' => env('DEBUGBAR_EDITOR', 'phpstorm'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Remote Path Mapping
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using a remote dev server, like Laravel Homestead, Docker, or
| even a remote VPS, it will be necessary to specify your path mapping.
|
| Leaving one, or both of these, empty or null will not trigger the remote
| URL changes and Debugbar will treat your editor links as local files.
|
| "remote_sites_path" is an absolute base path for your sites or projects
| in Homestead, Vagrant, Docker, or another remote development server.
|
| Example value: "/home/vagrant/Code"
|
| "local_sites_path" is an absolute base path for your sites or projects
| on your local computer where your IDE or code editor is running on.
|
| Example values: "/Users/<name>/Code", "C:\Users\<name>\Documents\Code"
|
*/

'remote_sites_path' => env('DEBUGBAR_REMOTE_SITES_PATH', ''),
'local_sites_path' => env('DEBUGBAR_LOCAL_SITES_PATH', ''),

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Vendors
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Vendor files are included by default, but can be set to false.
 | This can also be set to 'js' or 'css', to only include javascript or css vendor files.
 | Vendor files are for css: font-awesome (including fonts) and highlight.js (css files)
 | and for js: jquery and highlight.js
 | So if you want syntax highlighting, set it to true.
 | jQuery is set to not conflict with existing jQuery scripts.
 |
 */

'include_vendors' => true,

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Capture Ajax Requests
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | The Debugbar can capture Ajax requests and display them. If you don't want this (ie. because of errors),
 | you can use this option to disable sending the data through the headers.
 |
 | Optionally, you can also send ServerTiming headers on ajax requests for the Chrome DevTools.
 |
 | Note for your request to be identified as ajax requests they must either send the header
 | X-Requested-With with the value XMLHttpRequest (most JS libraries send this), or have application/json as a Accept header.
 */

'capture_ajax' => true,
'add_ajax_timing' => false,

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Custom Error Handler for Deprecated warnings
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | When enabled, the Debugbar shows deprecated warnings for Symfony components
 | in the Messages tab.
 |
 */
'error_handler' => false,

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Clockwork integration
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | The Debugbar can emulate the Clockwork headers, so you can use the Chrome
 | Extension, without the server-side code. It uses Debugbar collectors instead.
 |
 */
'clockwork' => false,

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | DataCollectors
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Enable/disable DataCollectors
 |
 */

'collectors' => [
    'phpinfo'         => true,  // Php version
    'messages'        => true,  // Messages
    'time'            => true,  // Time Datalogger
    'memory'          => true,  // Memory usage
    'exceptions'      => true,  // Exception displayer
    'log'             => true,  // Logs from Monolog (merged in messages if enabled)
    'db'              => true,  // Show database (PDO) queries and bindings
    'views'           => true,  // Views with their data
    'route'           => true,  // Current route information
    'auth'            => false, // Display Laravel authentication status
    'gate'            => true,  // Display Laravel Gate checks
    'session'         => true,  // Display session data
    'symfony_request' => true,  // Only one can be enabled..
    'mail'            => true,  // Catch mail messages
    'laravel'         => false, // Laravel version and environment
    'events'          => false, // All events fired
    'default_request' => false, // Regular or special Symfony request logger
    'logs'            => false, // Add the latest log messages
    'files'           => false, // Show the included files
    'config'          => false, // Display config settings
    'cache'           => false, // Display cache events
    'models'          => true,  // Display models
    'livewire'        => true,  // Display Livewire (when available)
],

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Extra options
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Configure some DataCollectors
 |
 */

'options' => [
    'auth' => [
        'show_name' => true,   // Also show the users name/email in the debugbar
    ],
    'db' => [
        'with_params'       => true,   // Render SQL with the parameters substituted
        'backtrace'         => true,   // Use a backtrace to find the origin of the query in your files.
        'backtrace_exclude_paths' => [],   // Paths to exclude from backtrace. (in addition to defaults)
        'timeline'          => false,  // Add the queries to the timeline
        'duration_background'  => true,   // Show shaded background on each query relative to how long it took to execute.
        'explain' => [                 // Show EXPLAIN output on queries
            'enabled' => true,
            'types' => ['SELECT'],     // Deprecated setting, is always only SELECT
        ],
        'hints'             => false,    // Show hints for common mistakes
        'show_copy'         => false,    // Show copy button next to the query,
        'slow_threshold'    => false,   // Only track queries that last longer than this time in ms
    ],
    'mail' => [
        'full_log' => false,
    ],
    'views' => [
        'timeline' => true,  // Add the views to the timeline (Experimental)
        'data' => true,    //Note: Can slow down the application, because the data can be quite large..
        'exclude_paths' => [], // Add the paths which you don't want to appear in the views
    ],
    'route' => [
        'label' => true,  // show complete route on bar
    ],
    'logs' => [
        'file' => null,
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'values' => true, // collect cache values
    ],
],

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Inject Debugbar in Response
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Usually, the debugbar is added just before </body>, by listening to the
 | Response after the App is done. If you disable this, you have to add them
 | in your template yourself. See http://phpdebugbar.com/docs/rendering.html
 |
 */

'inject' => true,

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | DebugBar route prefix
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Sometimes you want to set route prefix to be used by DebugBar to load
 | its resources from. Usually the need comes from misconfigured web server or
 | from trying to overcome bugs like this: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97
 |
 */
'route_prefix' => '_debugbar',

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | DebugBar route domain
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | By default DebugBar route served from the same domain that request served.
 | To override default domain, specify it as a non-empty value.
 */
'route_domain' => null,

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | DebugBar theme
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Switches between light and dark theme. If set to auto it will respect system preferences
 | Possible values: auto, light, dark
 */
'theme' => env('DEBUGBAR_THEME', 'auto'),

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Backtrace stack limit
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | By default, the DebugBar limits the number of frames returned by the 'debug_backtrace()' function.
 | If you need larger stacktraces, you can increase this number. Setting it to 0 will result in no limit.
 */
'debug_backtrace_limit' => 50,
```

];
`

Comment: check this out and see if it helps, there are some issues with laravel-debugger and Flimanet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77167223/laravel-filament-very-slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some pictures to the question so I can understand it better. I always install Laravel Debugbar by following the specific instructions here (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

I think you haven't enabled their functions in the config/debugbar. Check it out and turn it on.

```
'collectors' => [
    'phpinfo'         => true,  // Php version
    'messages'        => true,  // Messages
    'time'            => true,  // Time Datalogger
    'memory'          => true,  // Memory usage
    'exceptions'      => true,  // Exception displayer
    'log'             => true,  // Logs from Monolog (merged in messages if enabled)
    'db'              => true,  // Show database (PDO) queries and bindings
    'views'           => true,  // Views with their data
    'route'           => true,  // Current route information
    'auth'            => false, // Display Laravel authentication status
    'gate'            => true,  // Display Laravel Gate checks
    'session'         => true,  // Display session data
    'symfony_request' => true,  // Only one can be enabled..
    'mail'            => true,  // Catch mail messages
    'laravel'         => false, // Laravel version and environment
    'events'          => false, // All events fired
    'default_request' => false, // Regular or special Symfony request logger
    'logs'            => false, // Add the latest log messages
    'files'           => false, // Show the included files
    'config'          => false, // Display config settings
    'cache'           => false, // Display cache events
    'models'          => true,  // Display models
    'livewire'        => true,  // Display Livewire (when available)
],
```

Some middleware may be blocking the Debugbar from collecting routes and views. Check the middleware again to see if any middleware is causing the problem.

Did you try CTRL + SHIFT + R? clear browser cache

Comment: i put the images you can show them in the link 
I do all the instructions below and it doesn't work

Comment: I think you haven't enabled their functions in the config/debugbar.

Comment: i edited the post you can show my debugbar  config file it no have any problem with it

Comment: i think you need clear browser cache